# How do I extract a string of text that lies between two (brackets) or n Bracklets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression or scripting code to select all the text between two outer brackets.

Example of message Body : some text(text here(possible text)text(possible text(more text)))end text

the result that i want Result: (text here(possible text)text(possible text(more text)))

the second example:

> (Jack Tomy)(Smith)(ti,ab(((Abbott near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy*
>   OR *array*)) OR (Abbott p/1 Point P/1 Care) OR ARCHITECT OR (CELL p/0
>   DYN)) OR ((Alere near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR
>   (Alere NEAR/5 (Triage P/1 System)) OR INRatio OR Afinion) OR
>   ((Beckman* p/1 Coulter near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*))
>   OR ((Beckman* p/0 Coulter) near/2 AU????) OR (UniCel* P/1 DxC) OR
>   (UniCel* p/1 DxI) OR ( Beckman* near/5 Access) OR (Access* p/1
>   Systeme) OR (CytoFLEX OR (cyto p/0 flex)) OR (UniCel* p/1 DxH) OR
>   ((Coulter* p/1 LH) OR Coulter*LH)) OR ((Ortho p/0 Clinical P/1
>   Diagnostics) OR VITROS OR (vitros* p/1 System*) OR (VITROS* p/1 ECiQ)
>   OR ORTHOTM OR (orthotm p/1 VISION) OR (ORTHO p/1 AutoVue*)) OR
>   ((Instrumentation p/0 Laboratories) OR HemosIL OR ACLTOP OR (ACL p/0
>   ELITE) OR (GEM* P/1 Premier) OR GEM*OPL) OR ((Radiometer near/10
>   (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR *array*)) OR (AQT?? p/0 FLEX) OR (ABL??
>   p/0 FLEX) OR HemoCue*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) OR StatStrip OR (STAT
>   p/0 PROFILE*) OR ((Nova p/0 Biomedical) near/1 Prime) OR STATPROFILE*)
>   OR (((Siemens p/0 Healthcare) near/10 (assay* OR test* OR analy* OR
>   *array*)) OR (ADVIA p/0 Centaur) OR (Dimension p/0 Vista) OR RAPIDPOINT))) and (ud(>20170101)) (see attachment)

the same thing I want to extract the text from "()" (Jack Tomy)(Smith)(ti,ab(((... my output jack Tomy Smith ti,ab(........)

.)

```
var messageBody = message.getPlainBody();
var ssFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id);

DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.getId()).addFile(ssFile);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(ssFile);
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.insertColumnAfter(sheet.getLastColumn());
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn() + 1)
    var values = range.getValues();
    values[0][sheet.getLastColumn()] = "Search Strategy";
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

    var y = messageBody.match(/\(.*\)/ig); //my regexp to extract the the text between ()
    if (y)
    values[i][values[i].length - 1] = y.toString();
    }
```

I've been trying for hours, I tired a lot of examples but failed. 
any help will be gratefully received.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add your attempted code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) everything between the two brackets:

```js
const str = 'some text(text here(possible text)text(possible text(more text)))end text';
const match = str.match(/\((.*)\)/);
console.log(match[0])
```

Comment: The `match` method returns an array of regex matches. Since you're only interested in the first match you grab the first element from the array.

Comment: I will add another  input condition could you test it

Comment: What's stopping you testing it?

Comment: Depends what you want your output to be because it's not clear from that example/

Comment: the same thing I want to extract the text from ()  (Jack Tomy)(Smith)(ti,ab(((... my output jack Tomy Smith ti,ab(.........)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167153/discussion-between-mokinex-and-andy).

Comment: no problem but could help me with this example I tried for hours.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "some text(text here(possible text)text(possible text(more text)))end text";
console.log(string.match(/.*?(\(.*\))[^\)]*/)[1]);
```

Comment: thanks, could you test my second example it doesn't work for me